# How to fix mismatched Results using #[launch] when upgrading from Rocket 0.5.0-rc.1 to rc.2?

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I'm trying to get a simple API up and running using rocket similar to [this repo](https://github.com/TatriX/realworld-rust-rocket):

```rust
//! main.rs
use ptb_api; // my crate

#[rocket::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), rocket::Error> {
    ptb_api::rocket().launch().await
}
```

```rust
//! lib.rs
use rocket::{get, launch, routes};

#[get("/")]
fn index() -> &'static str {
    "Hello, world!"
}

#[launch]
pub fn rocket() -> _ {
    rocket::build().mount("/", routes![index])
}
```

```toml
# Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
rocket = "0.5.0-rc.2"
```

When I attempt to build I get this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src\main.rs:4:46
  |
4 |   async fn main() -> Result<(), rocket::Error> {
  |  ____________________-------------------------_^
  | |                    |
  | |                    expected `Result<(), rocket::Error>` because of return type
5 | |     ptb_api::rocket().launch().await
6 | | }
  | |_^ expected `()`, found struct `Rocket`
  |
  = note: expected enum `Result<(), _>`
             found enum `Result<Rocket<Ignite>, _>`
```

I am using nearly the same code as the repo I linked above. I can't tell why the linked repo builds and mine fails. It should be worth noting that I am using rocket version `0.5.0-rc.2` and the linked repo was using `0.5.0-rc.1`. And after cloning the repo and upgrading it, the same problem occurs. So something changed in rocket between release candidates, just not sure what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [0.5.0-rc.1 docs](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.1/rocket/struct.Rocket.html#method.launch) show `launch`'s signature as:

```
pub async fn launch(self) -> Result<(), Error>
```

But the [0.5.0-rc.2 docs](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.2/rocket/struct.Rocket.html#method.launch) show `launch`'s signature as:

```
pub async fn launch(self) -> Result<Rocket<Ignite>, Error>
```

Thus, the return type using `#[launch]` no longer matches your signature in `main()` after upgrading. This can be fixed by simply returning `Ok` at the end of your function as shown [here](https://rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/guide/overview/#launching):

```
#[rocket::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), rocket::Error> {
    let _rocket = ptb_api::rocket().launch().await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: nice catch about the return type. I have tried what you suggested about updating main and I get this error:
```error[E0277]: `main` has invalid return type `Rocket<Ignite>`
  --> src/main.rs:50:19
   |
50 | async fn main() ->Result<Rocket<Ignite>, Error> {
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `main` can only return types that implement `Termination`
   |
   = help: the trait `Termination` is not implemented for `Rocket<Ignite>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Termination` for `Result<Rocket<Ignite>, rocket::Error>```
if I do Ok(()) works

Comment: by that I mean my original signature and Ok(()) so it really is returning a () like these docs suggest https://rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/guide/overview/#launching

Comment: @stegnerd Good catch, I'll update my answer with what you found.